# Why would CreateDefaultAssociatedGroups stop to ServerUnauthorizedAccessException after creating a site with CreateWeb?

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

I am using CSOM to create a site to SharePoint Online. Site is created correctly, but if I try to use CreateDefaultAssociatedGroups for that site, I get following exception

> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerUnauthorizedAccessException: Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.

Code is something like

```
Web web = ctx.Web;
Web newWeb = ctx.Web.CreateWeb("title", "leafurl", "description", "template", 1033, false);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
newWeb.CreateDefaultAssociatedGroups(string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty);
ctx.ExecuteQueryRetry();
```

So how come CSOM can create a site but it cannot create default associate groups for it?

*(Afterwards I would associate owner group, but I cannot do that without CreateDefaultAssociatedGroups because newWeb.AssociatedOwnerGroup would be null)*

EDIT:
Same thing happens if I do following

```
Web web = ctx.Web;
Web newWeb = ctx.Web.CreateWeb("title", "leafurl", "description", "template", 1033, false);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
newWeb.AssociatedVisitorGroup = null;
newWeb.AssociatedMemberGroup = null;
newWeb.AssociatedOwnerGroup = null;
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

EDIT2:
It seems that **CreateDefaultAssociatedGroups** does add the groups to SharePoint. At least they are visible in _layouts/15/User.aspx but e.g. _api/web/associatedOwnerGroup returns

```
<d:AssociatedOwnerGroup xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" m:null="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is **DenyAddAndCustomizePages** setting of site collection. It is automatically enabled for any site collection you create via SharePoint online by using the beautiful *Create a site* tool (Team site or Communication site). If you create sitecollection via https://TENANT-admin.sharepoint.com it is not enabled.

Solution is to use PowerShell and disable that property

```
Connect-SPOService
Set-SPOSite https://TENANT.sharepoint.com/sites/sitecollection -DenyAddAndCustomizePages 0
```

You can check the current state of property with

```
$site = Get-SPOSite https://TENANT.sharepoint.com/sites/sitecollection
$site.DenyAddAndCustomizePages
```

I found info about this from https://dannyjessee.com/blog/index.php/2017/07/sharepoint-online-modern-team-sites-are-noscript-sites-but-communication-sites-are-not/

Comment: Thank you so much! Stupid functionality!!!

Answer (score 0):

Groups are created at the Site Collection level. To see this, go to a subsite, Site Settings, People and Groups, and on the left click More. All of the groups in the Site Collection will be displayed. (Or better, try to create a "Managers" group in one subsite when another site owner has already created one from their site.)

As Site Owners can create subsites, and typically create groups, there must be something odd about the top level site permissions of the account being used by the CSOM code.

So, it could either be:

- Lack of the CSOM account's permissions for the top level site, or
- The groups already exist. (created for another subsite)

There are other examples of what a Site Owner cannot do without at least limited permissions to the top level site. One is: subsite owner can't save a site as a template without write permissions to the Site Template Gallery in the top level site.